# How to execute query, group result set rows, and convert to XML?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, mysqli

I have a problem. I made the following code to create an array for the XML I want:

```
$BusinessId = $_GET["businessid"];
$CustomerCode = $_GET["customerid"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Code=".$CustomerCode." AND BusinessId=".$BusinessId;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$CustomerId = $row["Id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Albums WHERE CustomerId=".$CustomerId." ORDER BY Id DESC";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql);

$arr_albums = array();

while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    $arr_images = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ImagesWithAlbum WHERE AlbumId=".$row1["Id"]." ORDER BY ImageId ASC";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Images WHERE Id=".$row2["ImageId"];
        $result3 = $conn->query($sql);
        $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

        $image_array = array(
        array(
            'Id'=>$row3["Id"],
            'Name'=>$row3["Name"])
        );

        $arr_images[] = $image_array;
    }

    $album_array = array(
        array(
            'Id'=>$row1["Id"],
            'Image'=>$arr_images)
        );

    $arr_albums[] = $album_array;
}
```

Now I want to create a XML out of this array, so I created this code:

```
function toXml(SimpleXMLElement $xml, array $data, $mainKey = null)
{   
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // if the key is an integer, it needs text with it to actually work.
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            $key = $mainKey ? : "key_$key";
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $childXml = $xml->addChild($key);
            toXml($childXml, $value);
        } else {
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }   
    }   
    return $xml;
}

// Pretty print Xml
function formatXml($simpleXMLElement)
{
    $xmlDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $xmlDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xmlDocument->formatOutput = true;
    $xmlDocument->loadXML($simpleXMLElement->asXML());

    return $xmlDocument->saveXML();
}

$xml = toXml(new SimpleXMLElement('<Albums/>'), $arr_albums, 'Album');
$output = $xml->asXML();

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print formatXml($xml);
```

The problem is that the xml is almost like the way I want, except for 1 tag in the XML. The tags are as following:

```
<Albums>
<Album>
<Id>4</Id>
<Images>
<key_0>
<Image>
<Id>2</Id>
<Name>viktor_rood.png</Name>
</Image>
</key_0>
<key_1>
<Image>
<Id>5</Id>
<Name>viktor_geel.png</Name>
</Image>
</key_1>
<key_2>
<Image>
<Id>7</Id>
<Name>viktor_paars.png</Name>
</Image>
</key_2>
<key_3>
<Image>
<Id>8</Id>
<Name>viktor_aqua.png</Name>
</Image>
</key_3>
</Images>
</Album>
</Albums>
```

Now how can I remove the `key_x` tag, because I don't need that!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: You could probably do this whole thing with 1 or 2 queries using `join`s. Parameterize your queries though.

Comment: Anyway, I suspect your problem is that array_merge() doesn't do what you think it does. Here's a clue: The [array_merge docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) say "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will **overwrite** the previous one" (my bold). I assume what you're really trying to do is just add another item to the array, not merge/overwrite it. But yeah, there's no need for so many separate queries here - learn about `INNER JOIN` in SQL.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that, but I updated my code. I got it working, but still 1 small problem. I have a weird tag in my XML from that Array?

Comment: which one is "weird" in your view? You mean the `<key_0>` and so on, perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that in my question at the bottom. I mean the <key_x> tag. How can I remove that one?

Comment: Do NOT perform iterated queries.  These nested loops and query are a performance nightmare.  As stated above, it is time to rescript with JOINs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing an unnecessary level of array to `$image_array` and `$album_array`, which is what is resulting in the `key_*` tags. If you remove that it should get rid of those keys:

```
$image_array = array(
    'Id'=>$row3["Id"],
    'Name'=>$row3["Name"]
);

$album_array = array(
    'Id'=>$row1["Id"],
    'Images'=>$arr_images
);
```

You also need to change your `toXML` function to supply a `$mainkey` value when you recurse. In this version I've chosen to strip the last character off the current key (so for `Images` you would get `Image` tags underneath them):

```
function toXml(SimpleXMLElement $xml, array $data, $mainKey = null)
{   
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // if the key is an integer, it needs text with it to actually work.
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            $key = $mainKey ? : "key_$key";
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $childXml = $xml->addChild($key);
            toXml($childXml, $value, substr($key, 0, -1));
        } else {
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }   
    }   
    return $xml;
}
```

For your data you should then get a result like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Albums>
  <Album>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <Images>
      <Image>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>viktor_rood.png</Name>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <Name>viktor_geel.png</Name>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <Name>viktor_paars.png</Name>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Id>8</Id>
        <Name>viktor_aqua.png</Name>
      </Image>
    </Images>
  </Album>
</Albums>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/B6Qfl)

Comment: Sorry, but now the tag `<Image>` is gone. Still the `<key_x>` tag!?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I didn't scroll down far enough in your code, you have the same issue with `$album_array`. See my edit...

Comment: Now I have <Image> arround all the images and still <key_x> foreach image?
`<Album>
<Id>4</Id>
<Image>
<key_0>
<Id>2</Id>
<Name>viktor_rood.png</Name>
</key_0>
<key_1>
<Id>5</Id>
<Naam>viktor_geel.png</Naam>
</key_1>
<key_2>
<Id>7</Id>
<Name>viktor_paars.png</Name>
</key_2>
<key_3>
<Id>8</Id>
<Name>viktor_aqua.png</Name>
</key_3>
</Image>
</Album>`

Comment: I want `<Image>` on the place of `<key_x>`

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I think the issue is that when you call `toXML` recursively, you need to supply a value for `$mainkey`. Take a look at https://3v4l.org/B6Qfl note I've changed the tag above the images to `Images` from `Image`

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk good to hear! I'll update the answer with the changes to the `toXML` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Prepared statement? **Check.**
- JOIN clauses? **Check.**

...

- Nested loops? **Gone.**
- Iterated queries? **Gone.**
- Temporary key manipulations? **Gone.**
- Recursion? **Gone.**

TBH, I did not test the query and I don't do a lot of XML work.  If something isn't right, I am happy to fix it.  Look at how clean, secure, and readable your script can be...

Partially Code: ([Demo from a sample result set](https://3v4l.org/pt408)) ([Demo with a second album](https://3v4l.org/HJTIV))

```
function formatXml($simpleXMLElement) {
    $xmlDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $xmlDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xmlDocument->formatOutput = true;
    $xmlDocument->loadXML($simpleXMLElement->asXML());
    return $xmlDocument->saveXML();
}

if (isset($_GET["businessid"], $_GET["customerid"])) {
    $sql = "SELECT Albums.Id, Images.Id, Images.Name
            FROM Customers
            JOIN Albums ON Customer.Id = Albums.CustomerId
            JOIN ImagesWithAlbum ON Albums.Id = ImagesWithAlbum.AlbumId
            JOIN Images ON ImagesWithAlbum.ImageId = Images.Id
            WHERE Customers.Code = ? AND Customers.BusinessId = ?
            ORDER BY Id DESC, ImageId";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_GET["businessid"], $_GET["customerid"]); // use 'ii' if both integers
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($albumId, $imageId, $imageName);
    $albums = new SimpleXMLElement('<Albums/>');
    $currentAlbumId = null;
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if ($currentAlbumId !== $albumId) {
            $album = $albums->addChild('Album');
            $album->addChild('Id', $albumId);
            $images = $album->addChild('Images');
        }
        $image = $images->addChild('Image');
        $image->addChild('Id', $imageId)
        $image->addChild('Name', $imageName);
        $currentAlbumId = $albumId;
    }
    echo formatXml($albums);
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Albums>
  <Album>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <Images>
      <Image>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>viktor_rood.png</Name>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <Name>viktor_geel.png</Name>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <Name>viktor_paars.png</Name>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Id>8</Id>
        <Name>viktor_aqua.png</Name>
      </Image>
    </Images>
  </Album>
</Albums>
```